# I'm trying to create a SelectInput component with React that Delete an option from multiple options

Tags: reactjs, typescript, input, components, react-select

My SelectInput component have a property to have multiples options the issue is that I need to click on a specific option and delete that option inside value of the input similar to the react-select example below.
[image]

[React-select component](https://react-select.com/home)

My problem is that I don't know how to achieve that with my own SelectInput component there is any example that I can follow or any answer of how to do that?

There is my code if is needed:

This is the function that i use to manage my option selections:

```
const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState<Option[]>([]);
```

```
    const handleOptionSelect = (option: Option) => {
      if (multi) {
        const isSelected = selectedOptions.some((selectedOption) => selectedOption.value === option.value);
    
        if (isSelected) {
          const updatedOptions = selectedOptions.filter((selectedOption) => selectedOption.value !== option.value);
          setSelectedOptions(updatedOptions);
        } else {
          setSelectedOptions([...selectedOptions, option]);
        }
      } else {
        setSelectedOptions([option]);
        setIsDropdownOpen(false);
      }
    };
```

And this is my input and how i show the selected options inside:

```
    <input
    type="text"
    className="select-input__input"
    placeholder={placeholder}
    readOnly={readOnly}
    value={selectedOptions.length > 0 ? selectedOptions.map((option) => option.label).join(' ') : searchText}
    onChange={handleInputChange}
    {...props}
    onClick={toggleDropdown}
  />
```

Writing my question here I realize that stack overflow has something like I want to achieve with my component:
[image]

Comment: So your question is how to remove those you click on?